# Glassfish 3 - Loading images from a static server

Tags: glassfish-3

I'm trying to load images (and other static content) from a server outside of my web application which is deployed to **Glassfish v3**. I have the following configs in the **web.xml** but it does not work on Glassfish (but it works on Tomcat):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ExternalImagesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.servlet.HttpProxyServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>RemoteURI</param-name>
        <param-value>http://ip.of.second.server/website-files</param-value>
    </init-param>   
    <init-param>
        <param-name>AllowedContentTypes</param-name>
        <param-value>image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ExternalImagesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Where **ip.of.second.server** is an actual IP address of the server. I have the file called **website-files.xml** defined as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="d:/internet/website/images" />
```

And website-files.xml is saved to **glassfish\domains\domain1\config** directory. But Glassfish does not pick up this config file.

I have looked at Oracle Glassfish configuration doco but there's no mention on how you can reference images from a different server.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved it based on an old thread relating to Glassfish version 2 that I found on Google after two days of search.

In case anyone is interested in the solution, here it is:

1) Create a file called **sun-web.xml** directly under **Webcontent\WEB-INF** directory and add the following configuration to this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.0 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-web-app_3_0-0.dtd">
<sun-web-app>
   <property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/images/* dir=d:/internet/website" />
   <property name="alternatedocroot_2" value="from=/files/* dir=d:/internet/website" />
</sun-web-app>
```

2) Remove the **servlet** and **servlet-mapping** configurations from **web.xml** file (like I did above). **Note**: The above would work if you were to use *Tomcat*.

3) Delete the **website-files.xml** from **glassfish\domains\domain1\config** directory as this file is not needed by Glassfish: **Note**: This file is needed by *Tomcat*.